# Aldebaran robotics pepper not displaying android OS settings

Tags: robotics, pepper

I have an Aldebaran Pepper robot, and I have been trying to access the settings of Peppers tablet so I can access Bluetooth and the tablets IP on android OS. Several people have said that all I have to do is swipe on the screen and the settings icon will appear, that does not happen. The only thing that displays on the screen is the multicolored circles, and if I ask pepper to show her settings she will open the same settings you see if you were put her IP address into a web browser but beyond that I can't access any further settings. Does anyone have any idea why? I would appreciate the help.

Thanks!
Have a good day!

I tried everything and I was expecting android OS settings to appear.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you are connected via ssh with the pepper with NaoQI 2.5 (ssh nao@pepper.local) you can run the following command to open the settings:

```
qicli call ALTabletService._openSettings
```

Comment: so when I am connected to pepper via android studio I just run this command?

Comment: If you don't have NaoQi 2.5 then you can do it via adb "adb shell am start -a android.settings.SETTINGS" when connected to the robot via adb.